# Inserting values into newly created table from a pre-existing table using a cursor and for loop - Snowflake SQL (classic web interface)

Tags: for-loop, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

I'm trying to insert values into a new table in the classic Snowflake SQL web interface using data from a table that was already created, a cursor, and a for loop. My goal is to insert new information and information from the original table into the new table, but when I try and run my code, there is an error where I am referring to the column of my original table. (See code below)

```
-- Creation and inserting values into table invoice_original 
create temporary table invoice_original (id integer, price number(12,2));
insert into invoice_original (id, price) values
  (1, 11.11),
  (2, 22.22);
  
  
--  Creates final empty table invoice_final
create temporary table invoice_final (
  study_number varchar,
  price varchar,
  price_type varchar);
  

execute immediate $$
declare
  c1 cursor for select price from invoice_original;
begin
  for record in c1 do
        insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
        values('1', record.price, 'Dollars');
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

My end goal is to have the resulting table invoice_final with 3 columns - study_number, price, and price_type where the price value comes from the invoice_original table. The error I'm currently getting is:

Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 6 at position 8 : SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 20 invalid identifier 'RECORD.PRICE'.

Does anyone know why the record.price is not capturing the price value from the invoice_original table?

Comment: Why can't a simple insert be used rather then ```cursor-- loop```.    ```insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) select '1', io.price, 'Dollars' from invoice_original io; ```

Comment: Sorry - should've been more clear... my real issue is for a code more complex than this simplified example but this was the root of my problem

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of type of dynamic SQL that do not handle the cursor name, and thus give this error if you push it into a single name temp value it will work:

```
  for record in c1 do
        let temp_price number := record.price;
        insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
        values('1', temp_price, 'Dollars');
  end for;
```

- this sql has not been run, and could be the wrong format, but it is the base issue.

Also this really looks like an INSERT would work, but I also assume this is the nature of simplify the question down.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why, but this format of code didn't work for me until I modified temp_price to :temp_price in the values () part of the insert statement.

Comment: hmm, I have seen that also, but I am sure some of the examples use the cursor/temp variable directly without the `:temp_price` form.. lets agree it's not consistently consistent.

Comment: Yes, I had success once I declared temp_price outside of the for loop and then referring to it by ':temp_price'

Comment: Here is the link to working with variables that explains the behavior:https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#working-with-variables

Comment: @JimDemitriou the same page, but really it's the binding rules section that is the answer, as a huge number use the variables in a unbound form, and there is very little examples of using them in other SQL, it's rather inconsistent, but it is what it is... https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding

Answer (score 0):

See the following for details on working with variables:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#working-with-variables

The revised code below functions as desired:

```
-- Creation and inserting values into table invoice_original
        create
        or replace temporary table invoice_original (id integer, price number(12, 2));
    insert into
        invoice_original (id, price)
    values
        (1, 11.11),
        (2, 22.22);
    --  Creates final empty table invoice_final
        create
        or replace temporary table invoice_final (
            study_number varchar,
            price number(12, 2),
            price_type varchar
        );
    execute immediate $$
    declare
      
      new_price number(12,2);
      c1 cursor for select price from invoice_original;
    begin
      for record in c1 do
            new_price := record.price;
            insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) values('1',:new_price, 'Dollars');
      end for;
    end;
    $$;
```

Note that I changed the target table definition for price to NUMBER (12,2) instead of VARCHAR, and assigned the record.price to a local variable that was passed to the insert statement as :new_price.

That all said ... I would strongly recommend against this approach for loading tables for performance reasons.  You can replace all of this with an INSERT .. AS ... SELECT.

Always opt for set based processing over cursor / loop / row based processing with Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html

Comment: Thanks so much!! My real issue is for a code more complex than this simplified example but this was the root of my problem and the declaration of the variable outside of the loop along with referring to it by ':new_price' was key. Thanks again!